# Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'sa'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, informatica, mdm

Im installing the MDM of Informatica.
MDM 10.2 - Jboss 6.4 EAP - SQL Server 11 - Windows Server 2008 R2.

During the creation of the schema 'sip_ant.bat create_bpm' i got this error

**Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'sa'.**
(Same eeror with another user)

I already tried to use the **Auth Mixed Mode** and restarted the instance of the DB.

Error received is

```
D:\informatica\database\bin\common.xml:248: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\informatica\database\bin\mssql\database.xml:1214: Launched command return error code 1.
```

And that's the line of database.xml:1214 that refers:

```
 collation_name="${activevos.collation}" param2="&quot;${dbpath_short}&quot;" param1="${activevos.password}">
```

Im able to login via SQLCMD on CMD with user 'sa' and other users.

MDM and SQL Server are on different Machine.

Any suggestion?

Comment: We had a similar issue using OSQL; it started failing since KB4057113 has been deployed. We worked around this issue by using the Windows session user (i.e. OSQL -E) instead of SA in our scripts. HTH.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Problem was due to Customer configured another Default SQL port to use on SQL Management.

Comment: Could you maybe provide some information as to how to fix the issue?

Comment: As i said, they were not using the default SQL port, they were using a different one.

Answer (score 5):

By default SQL Server will track failed logins and register it in the server log along with the reason. So check out your errorlog and look for errors 18456.

You can read the log by using SQL Server Management Studio by going to server, Management, SQL Server Logs, Current. Or any other way you prefer.

You'll find something like this:

```
2018-02-27 13:51:26.120 Logon        Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.
2018-02-27 13:51:26.120 Logon        Login failed for user 'fasd'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.80.62.89]
```

Comment: Main problem is that failed login starting from this application is not written inside log. Meanwhile fail login using SQLCMD for example, is written inside the log that i found using SQL Mngmt studio.

Comment: This post helped me with my situation, thanks! :) I was trying to use an AD user account, but was receiving "account not found." I created a SQLDB user, which only had access to that DB, and everything is working smoothly!

Answer (score 1):

server=Yourservername,portnumber

You can put the above in your connection string